# Dynamic Navigation elements width adjustment with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamic, width, adjustment

I have a standard horizontal dropdown Navigation menu with 3 Levels. What I want to do via JS, is to dynamically adjust the width of top / level 1 `Element` in the `Navigation`, no matter how many of them are put in by the end user. The Website is run on Joomla.

Here's the js code I wrote. It's short and simple. I've tried multiple ways to write it, in case there was a syntax error, but I still doesn't affect the width of the level 1 elements.

```
// load site, get the number of level 1 Elements

window.onload = function() { 

var elements_count = document.getElementsByClassName('level1').length;

// Get required width for level 1 elements

var rest = 1000 % elements_count;
var elements_width = (1000 - rest) / elements_count;

// adjust width of level 1 Elements

elements.style.width = elements_width + 'px';

}
```

I'd be grateful for any advice ;)

Comment: are your "level1" elements in source html or created in a dynamic way? if it's the -dynamic- case then when onload() is called, these elements may not yet be reachable

Comment: Yes, the whole navigation is created dynamically by a module I installed on my Joomla site. But, the elements_width is calculated properly. If I insert "alert(elements_width)" for example, the announced calculated width is correct.